# How to uncheck this automatically from all wordpress posts?

Tags: plugins

How do I automatically deselect this option from all posts, without having to edit post by post?

```
<div class="forminp forminp-onoff_checkbox">
                <input id="a3_pvc_activated" name="a3_pvc_activated" class="a3_pvc_activated" type="checkbox" value="false" checked_label="ON" unchecked_label="OFF" checked="checked">

                <label for="a3_pvc_activated">Activate on this item</label>
            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What plugin does that come from? I'd check your wp_postmeta table to see if it's storing this as a3_pvc_activated in there. Then you can just change or delete all of the rows for that.

Comment: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/page-views-count/, This plugin I'm using.